# Is there a way to monkeypatch a django contrib exception so that tests will pass?

Tags: django

These are the two apps in my `INSTALLED_APPS` list which is giving me a problem.

1. django.contrib.messages
2. sentry.client

One unit test in particular is doing an `assertRaises` expecting a `django.contrib.messages.api.MessageFailure`.

`sentry.client` installs a signal handler that listens for [got-request-exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#got-request-exception).
During the test execution, the signal handler attempts to log the exception to sentry & this cause sentry.client to fail with a `HTTP Error 400: BAD REQUEST`. The sentry code says that it will avoid the logging if the exception type possesses an attribute ``.

Where can I monkeypatch `django.contrib.messages.api.MessageFailure` like so:

```
MessageFailure.skip_sentry = True
```

Obviously I don't want to change the django test sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used sentry before, but to add a `skip_entry` attribute to the `MessageFailure` class you use a [mix-in](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/4540/print). Add the following code in a module that's guaranteed to run when your Django server starts up [any `models.py` should work]:

```
from django.contrib.messages.api import MessageFailure
class MessageFailureMixin:
    skip_sentry = True
MessageFailure.__bases__ += (MessageFailureMixin,)
```

Comment: Simon, It works. You are a genius. I learnt something new about python today, thanks to you.